# Reply mail to multi address using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have email address "a@gmail.com" send mail to email address "b@gmail.com".
And i want reply mail to email address "a@gmail" and add more email address "c@gmail.com". I read google docs and followed but it didn't work. Just only email address "a@gmail.com" received, email address "c@gmail.com" have not received the mail. I don't know where I'm wrong ??? Thanks for your interest!

```
function replyToMutiAddress(){

  var thread = GmailApp.getThreadById("16dxxxxxxba6");
  var mgs = thread.getMessages()[0];
  var option = {    
      replyTo: "a@gmail.com,c@gmail.com",
      cc: "",
      bcc: "",
      htmlBody: "b@gmail.com reply mail to a@gmail.com and add c@gmail.com"
  }
  mgs.reply("",option);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this answer?

[The official document of Sending Email](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#sending_messages) says as follows.

> If you're trying to send a reply and want the email to thread, make sure that:
>
> 1. The Subject headers match
> 2. The References and In-Reply-To headers follow the RFC 2822 standard.

For above situation, the email is replied using Gmail API. Before you run the script, please enable Gmail API at [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

#### Sample script:

```
function replyToMutiAdress(){
  var body = "sample body";
  var additionalEmailAddress = "c@gmail.com";
  var thread = GmailApp.getThreadById("16dxxxxxxba6");
  var mgs = thread.getMessages()[0];
  var message = Gmail.Users.Messages.get("me", mgs.getId());
  var head = 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n';
  var data = message.payload.headers.reduce(function(s, e) {
    if (e.name.toUpperCase() == "MESSAGE-ID") {
      s += "References: " + e.value + "\r\nIn-Reply-To: " + e.value + "\r\n";
    } else if (e.name == "Subject") {
      s += e.name + ": " + e.value + "\r\n";
    } else if (e.name == "From") {
      s += "To: " + e.value + "," + additionalEmailAddress + "\r\n";
    } else if (e.name == "To") {
      s += "From: " + e.value + "\r\n";
    }
    return s;
  }, head);
  data += "\r\n" + body;
  var res = Gmail.Users.Messages.send({raw: Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(data)}, "me");
}
```

- In this sample script, `References` and `In-Reply-To` are included in the header.
- `c@gmail.com` is added as the additional email address.

#### References:

- [Sending Email](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#sending_messages)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)
- [Users.messages: send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, but i don't want use cc c@gmail.com and if i send to c@gmail.com this mail not in thread (ThreadID). Is there any other way ? because gmail box in web when reply mail maybe add more email address so I think there's a way we don't know ^^

Comment: @Naoa Lee Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? An email is sent from `a@gmail.com` to `b@gmail.com`. And when the reply mail is sent from `b@gmail.com` to `a@gmail.com`, you want to add the email address of `c@gmail.com`. In the modified script, achieves it with Gmail API. But I'm not sure whether this is the goal you want. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize, again.